# Python Flask socketIO server not running

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I have this simple script with a Flask webserver. When I try to run the Python script, nothing happens, it just freezes.

I have already installed eventlet but this has not fixed the issue.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="statics", template_folder="templates")
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')


@socketio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print(sid, 'connected')


@socketio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print(sid, 'disconnected')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

How can I stop this script from freezing and make it serve the webpage?

Comment: what do you mean by "it freezes"?, if your doing something wrong there should be a log provided by the flask in terminal, besides, how did you write your client side code? provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by 'it freezes' but if it means you don't get any output in the terminal for debugging, you can fix that by setting debug mode to true using:

```py
socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is if we dont use debug=True atleast we can see the website starting at localhost:5000. But when we add debug=True ,we get nothing at the localhost:5000.All we can see in the terminal is this:

```
 * Restarting with watchdog (windowsapi)
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 118-201-611
```